# Changing The calendar core of Suitecrm to Persian Calendar (shamsi)

Tags: php, calendar, sugarcrm, persian, suitecrm

i'm trying to changing the calendar core of suitecrm to persian Calendar or jalali calendar and using jDateTime function to change it to jalali.

suitecrm on github : 
[suitecrm](https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM)

jalali Function on github : 

[sallar/jDateTime](https://github.com/sallar/jDateTime)

Comment: What you have tried? What issues you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is relevant. However, It is possible to change the labels in the calendar. For instance.

copy:
modules/Calendar/language/en_us.lang.php or .lang.php

to: 
custom/modules/Calendar/language/en_us.lang.php or .lang.php

And then edit the following to match the Persian calendar.

```
        $mod_list_strings = array(
        'dom_cal_weekdays' =>
            array(
                "Sun",
                "Mon",
                "Tue",
                "Wed",
                "Thu",
                "Fri",
                "Sat",
            ),
        'dom_cal_weekdays_long' =>
            array(
                "Sunday",
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday",
            ),
        'dom_cal_month' =>
            array(
                "",
                "Jan",
                "Feb",
                "Mar",
                "Apr",
                "May",
                "Jun",
                "Jul",
                "Aug",
                "Sep",
                "Oct",
                "Nov",
                "Dec",
            ),
        'dom_cal_month_long' =>
            array(
                "",
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December",
            ),
    );
```

If there are differences in terms of the number of days in each month etc. then you will need to override the index.php file in order to change how the calendar works.